# Acessing elements in a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

Been searching around the site but I can not find a solution that seems to work for me. I have a list of what I am assuming are tuples with 2 elements in them each. I would like to iterate over the list with tuples and break apart each tuple into a list.

data:

```
[('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)]
```

expected 2 lists countaining:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension as:

```
lst = [('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)] 
l1 = [elt[0] for elt in lst]
l2 = [elt[1] for elt in lst]
```

Or can be done in a single loop as:

```
l1, l2 = [], []
for elt in lst:
    l1.append(elt[0])
    l2.append(elt[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

The most beautiful way to do this in a pythonic way is actually unzipping the tuples

```
zipped = [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("C", 3)]    
unzipped_object = zip(*zipped)
unzipped_list = list(unzipped_object)
print(unzipped_list)
```

output:

> [('a', 'b', 'C'), (1, 2, 3)]

Answer (score 1):

If you are having a hard time with list comprehension here's the long and more readable version.
The other advantage is that this version is using a single for loop.

```
lst = [('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)] 

list1 = []
list2 = []
for couple in lst:
    list1.append(couple[0])
    list2.append(couple[1])

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use for loop.

```py
lst = [('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)]
l1 = []
l2 = []
for tup in lst:
    l1.append(tup[0])
    l2.append(tup[1])
```